# Counting Paths for Forming the Word BANANA in a 3 x3 Grid: How Many Ways?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, graph-theory, permutations, word-problem

---

**Hi. This is a Kangaroo 2023 Question.**

In how many different ways can the word BANANA be read from the following table by moving from one cell to another cell with which it shares an edge? Cells may be visited more than once.

```
B A N 
A N A 
N A N
```

**(A) 14 (B) 84 (C) 28 (D) 56​ (E) other value**

Also, there's a variation of this question, with this table:

```
B A B 
A N A 
B A B
```

The answer for the first is 84, but I can't figure out why.

My attempts were to try to recreate the table, considering how many possibilities we have for paths and each cell:

```
2 2 2
2 4 3
2 3 2
```

And I even thought about the following path:

```
2*2*(2+4)*(2+3)*(2+4) = 720
```

But I am far from the correct answer.

---

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4685734/math-competition-question-about-ways-to-spell-banana-in-a-square/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second grid is easier to analyze.  There are $4$ choices for the B.  From each of those choices, there are $2$ choices for the first A, $1$ choice for the N, $4$ choices for the second A, again $1$ choice for the N, and finally another $4$ choices for the third A.  Thus, there are $4 \cdot 2 \cdot 4 \cdot 4 = 128$ paths that work in the second grid.

As for the first grid, there are $2$ partial paths that give you a corner N as the first N.  From there, you can reach the second A either by backtracking or not backtracking.

If you don't backtrack, you have $2$ paths to another corner N for the second N (which gives you $2$ possibilities for the final A) and $1$ path to the center N (which gives you $4$ possibilities for the final A).  This accounts for $16$ total paths.

If you backtrack, you have $1$ path to a corner N as the second N (which gives you $2$ possibilities for the final A) and $1$ path to the center N (which gives you $4$ possibilities for the final A).  That accounts for another $12$ paths.

There are $2$ partial paths that give you the center N as the first N.  From there, you have $2$ ways to choose the second A that are adjacent to the B and $2$ ways to choose the second A that are not adjacent to the B.

If the second A is adjacent to the B, the second N can be a corner N ($2$ choices for the final A) or the center N ($4$ choices for the final A).  That accounts for another $24$ paths.

If the second A is not adjacent to the B, there are $2$ possible corner Ns to choose as the second N (each of which yields $2$ choices for the final A) and $1$ possible center N to choose as the second N (which yields $4$ choices for the final A).  That accounts for the final $32$ paths.

Thus, we have a total of $32+24+12+16=84$ paths.